# Run the unit test case in KrakenJS

Tags: node.js, kraken.js

When a [KrakenJS](https://github.com/paypal/kraken-js) project is created, there is this test folder that also generated.
However, there is no clear documentation how to run the test case.

Running the node index.js (in test folder) returns

> `/Users/rudygunawan/Documents/node-workspace/test/test/index.js:12
>   describe('index', function () { ^ ReferenceError: describe is not
>   defined
>       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rudygunawan/Documents/node-workspace/test/test/index.js:12:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:902:3`

Is this because I need to require("describe") and subsequently need to require(describe) first?

However after adding my assumption above and run "node index.js" from test folder, it does not return anything.

Is there any clear step that need to be performed to unit test the kraken project?

Answer (score 2):

`$ npm test`

should do (run it in the root folder of your krake.js project)

Answer (score 2):

```
$grunt test
```

configure which tests you want run in your GruntFile.js

Answer (score 1):

`npm test` should run the script from `package.json`, which is...

`grunt test` which runs the `tasks/jshint.js` and `tasks/mochacli.js` defined tasks, which ultimately loads `mocha` and runs the test script.

This can be short-circuited by running `mocha` directly, `mocha test/test/index.js`.

Mocha tests require a test-runner to set up the environment. You may favor writing future tests with `tape` and setting up the `tape` grunt task, or switching entirely to just having `npm test` run `tape test/*.js`, but that requires porting your test code from `mocha` to `tape`. It's mostly mechanical, but not always trivial work if you use mocha extensions.